# Hotel room availability

Tags: php

I want to check if any other room is available between check in and check out date. If a single day also booked between the submitted date, that room should not be included. Image shows the booked room. If I enter check in date like 2016-05-16 and check out date like 2016-05-21 then total no of booked room should be answered as 9 for hotel id=1
 [image]

My code is like-

='$i' and end_date='$i') and hotel_id='1'");

        $rows=mysql_fetch_row($sel);
        $count[]=$rows[0];
        echo '
'.$i.$rows[0];
        }
        foreach($count as $c)
        {
            echo "
---".$c;
        }
?>

Comment: Did you try to write some code? Can you post it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: yes I have tried this code : for($i=$_POST['start'];$i<=$_POST['end'];$i++)
  {
  //$sel=mysql_query("select book_id from tbl_room_book where (start_date>='$i' and end_date<='$i') or (start_date<='$i' and end_date>='$i') and hotel_id='1'");
  
  $rows=mysql_fetch_row($sel);
  $count[]=$rows[0];
  echo '<br>'.$i.$rows[0];
  }
  foreach($count as $c)
  {
   echo "<br>---".$c;
  }

Comment: @anjana - Post code in your Question, not here in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the SQL you are using so I will do a general approach trying to help you.

What you need there is the [SQL BETWEEN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp), in partitucular its negative, `NOT BETWEEN` in order to check if the room is empty.

The logic would be, I want to query every empty room, this means that today's date should not be between check in and check out dates.

Your query should look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE NOW() NOT BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

As a recommendation I suggest you to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get more accurate help in the future.

Hope this helped you :)